# Get ReAssignment time in days for employee on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an assignment table and I need to calculate the reassignment time in days for an employee once their old job has been completed.

Sample data here:

```
DROP TABLE #temptable

CREATE TABLE #temptable 
(
     [EmployeeID] INT, 
     [CustomerID] VARCHAR(255),
     [Startdate] SMALLDATETIME,
     [Enddate] SMALLDATETIME, 
     [AssignmentID] VARCHAR(255) 
)

INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
( 260, '75569', N'2019-06-17T00:00:00', N'2019-06-17T00:00:00', '1139597' ), 
( 365, '77234', N'2019-08-12T00:00:00', NULL, '1145495' ), 
( 365, '77234', N'2019-08-19T00:00:00', NULL, '1146052' ), 
( 531, '82224', N'2019-07-12T00:00:00', N'2019-07-16T00:00:00', '1142003' ), 
( 531, '73793', N'2019-07-07T00:00:00', N'2019-07-15T00:00:00', '1141124' ), 
( 567, '41965', N'2019-07-08T00:00:00', N'2019-07-08T00:00:00', '1141186' ), 
( 567, '73793', N'2019-07-05T00:00:00', N'2019-07-07T00:00:00', '1140546' ), 
( 626, '73720', N'2019-08-07T00:00:00', N'2019-08-12T00:00:00', '1144431' ), 
( 718, '94251', N'2019-07-18T00:00:00', N'2019-07-17T00:00:00', '1142617' ), 
( 718, '20116', N'2019-08-12T00:00:00', N'2019-08-12T00:00:00', '1144671' ), 
( 718, '20116', N'2019-07-18T00:00:00', N'2019-07-19T00:00:00', '1142808' ), 
( 759, '93619', N'2019-07-30T00:00:00', N'2019-07-30T00:00:00', '1143923' ), 
( 780, '89916', N'2019-07-15T00:00:00', N'2019-07-15T00:00:00', '1142101' ), 
( 780, '89916', N'2019-07-15T00:00:00', N'2019-07-25T00:00:00', '1142249' ), 
( 781, '65921', N'2019-09-16T00:00:00', N'2019-09-24T00:00:00', '1147642' ), 
( 933, '67299', N'2019-07-02T00:00:00', N'2019-07-02T00:00:00', '1140805' ), 
( 936, '93619', N'2019-07-21T00:00:00', N'2019-07-22T00:00:00', '1143013' ), 
( 1056, '71469', N'2019-09-25T00:00:00', NULL, '1148611' ), 
( 1114, '14617', N'2019-07-16T00:00:00', N'2019-07-25T00:00:00', '1143005' ), 
( 1262, '73793', N'2019-09-16T00:00:00', N'2019-09-16T00:00:00', '1147541' ), 
( 1262, '93626', N'2019-07-06T00:00:00', N'2019-07-07T00:00:00', '1141098' ), 
( 1262, '93626', N'2019-09-14T00:00:00', N'2019-09-14T00:00:00', '1147538' ), 
( 1920, '75569', N'2019-06-17T00:00:00', N'2019-06-26T00:00:00', '1139589' ), 
( 2019, '93626', N'2019-09-07T00:00:00', N'2019-09-07T00:00:00', '1147220' ), 
( 2248, '93626', N'2019-08-31T00:00:00', N'2019-09-01T00:00:00', '1146398' ), 
( 2248, '93626', N'2019-08-24T00:00:00', N'2019-08-25T00:00:00', '1145809' ), 
( 2248, '93626', N'2019-09-07T00:00:00', N'2019-09-08T00:00:00', '1146865' ), 
( 2248, '93626', N'2019-09-14T00:00:00', N'2019-09-15T00:00:00', '1147507' ), 
( 2772, '177', N'2019-07-08T00:00:00', N'2019-07-29T00:00:00', '1141670' ), 
( 2772, '146', N'2019-06-20T00:00:00', N'2019-06-30T00:00:00', '1139511' ), 
( 2772, '90730', N'2019-07-20T00:00:00', N'2019-07-27T00:00:00', '1142917' ), 
( 2772, '55154', N'2019-08-16T00:00:00', N'2019-08-16T00:00:00', '1145276' ), 
( 2772, '55154', N'2019-07-27T00:00:00', N'2019-07-27T00:00:00', '1143509' ), 
( 2772, '77234', N'2019-07-30T00:00:00', N'2019-08-11T00:00:00', '1144407' ), 
( 3026, '73793', N'2019-09-24T00:00:00', N'2019-09-24T00:00:00', '1148379' ), 
( 3026, '93626', N'2019-09-13T00:00:00', N'2019-09-15T00:00:00', '1147492' ), 
( 3158, '82228', N'2019-08-19T00:00:00', N'2019-08-22T00:00:00', '1145372' ), 
( 3158, '84283', N'2019-08-13T00:00:00', N'2019-08-16T00:00:00', '1144849' ), 
( 3422, '41965', N'2019-08-21T00:00:00', N'2019-09-17T00:00:00', '1145629' ), 
( 3666, '93626', N'2019-07-26T00:00:00', N'2019-07-28T00:00:00', '1143451' ), 
( 3666, '93626', N'2019-07-19T00:00:00', N'2019-07-21T00:00:00', '1142714' ),
( 100, '86985', N'2019-09-23T00:00:00', N'2019-09-26T00:00:00' , '11427d14' ), 
( 100, '86985', N'2019-09-23T00:00:00', N'2019-09-26T00:00:00'  ,'11427d14' )
```

I have used below script in order to get the days difference between the startdate and enddate.

**Requirement**: I need to get the re-assignment days of an employee on a job for different customer.

```
SELECT 
    EmployeeId,
    CustomerId,
    StartDate, EndDate,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, A, StartDate) AS duration
FROM
    (SELECT 
         *,
         LAG(EndDate) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId, CustomerId ORDER BY StartDate) AS A
     FROM #temptable
     WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL) b
ORDER BY 1
```

Here in my sample data:

- for `EmployeeId = 3666` there are two assignments for different customers but I do not get the duration between the two assignments.
- for `EmployeeId = 100`, it's the same customer of the two assignments so I do not want to show the -3 value.

Comment: I think you need a recursive CTE, but I find the question hard to follow.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Basically I want to calculate the time difference in days between an employee's old assignment and new assignment if the new assignment is for a different customer. My query might not be the accurate one. Please share any input if possible.

Answer (score 0):

try it : 
if join counts are not enough you can increase joins

```
select distinct 
t.EmployeeID,   t.CustomerID    ,   t.AssignmentID,
isnull(DATEDIFF(DAY,t.Startdate,t.Enddate),0)+
isnull(DATEDIFF(DAY,t1.Startdate,t1.Enddate),0)+
isnull(DATEDIFF(DAY,t2.Startdate,t2.Enddate),0)+
isnull(DATEDIFF(DAY,t3.Startdate,t3.Enddate),0)+
isnull(DATEDIFF(DAY,t4.Startdate,t4.Enddate),0) sum FROM #temptable t
left join #temptable t1 on t.EmployeeID = t1.EmployeeID and t.AssignmentID  != t1.AssignmentID
left join #temptable t2 on t.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID and t2.AssignmentID != t1.AssignmentID and t2.AssignmentID != t.AssignmentID
left join #temptable t3 on t.EmployeeID = t3.EmployeeID and t3.AssignmentID != t2.AssignmentID and t3.AssignmentID != t1.AssignmentID and t3.AssignmentID != t.AssignmentID
left join #temptable t4 on t.EmployeeID = t4.EmployeeID and t4.AssignmentID != t3.AssignmentID and t4.AssignmentID != t2.AssignmentID and t4.AssignmentID != t.AssignmentID
order by t.EmployeeID
```

Comment: sorry but your solution doesn't make no sense to my question.